# How to check if a list is empty? If I do "if (ptr!=NULL)" it doesn't work

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, stack

This is a part of a program that should moves a card from a `stack` and puts it to `topstacks`.

```
struct card {
    char face[3];
    char suit[4];
};
typedef struct card Card;

struct stack {
    Card cardd;
    struct stack *nextPtr;
};
typedef struct stack Stack;

int main() {
    Card deck[52];
    fill_deck(deck);
    randomize_deck(deck);
    Stack *stacks = calloc(10, sizeof(Stack));
    make_stacks(deck, stacks);    // all 10 stacks are filled with cards
    Stack *topstacks = calloc(4, sizeof(Stack));    // all 4 topstacks are EMPTY.
    /*
    scanf pos1, pos2 needed to apply the move the card in move_card
    */
    move_card(stacks, topstacks, pos1, pos2);
}

int move_card(Stack *stacks, Stack *topstacks, unsigned int pos1, unsigned int pos2) {
    Stack *prevfromPtr;
    Stack *fromPtr = &(stacks[pos1]);
    Stack *toPtr = &(topstacks[pos2]); 
    while (fromPtr->nextPtr != NULL) {
        prevfromPtr = fromPtr;
        fromPtr = fromPtr->nextPtr;
    }
    Stack *newmovingcard = calloc(1, sizeof(Stack));
    newmovingcard->cardd = fromPtr->cardd;
    newmovingcard->nextPtr = NULL; 
    if (toPtr != NULL) {    // this does not work. toPtr appears to be ALWAYS nonNULL, when it actually is NULL.
        while (toPtr->nextPtr != NULL) {
            toPtr = toPtr->nextPtr;
        } 
        toPtr->nextPtr = newmovingcard; 
        free(fromPtr);
        prevfromPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        return 0;
    } else {
        toPtr->cardd = newmovingcard->cardd;
        toPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        free(fromPtr);
        prevfromPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I don't know why, in `move_card` function, when I do `if (toPtr!=NULL)`, it appears non `NULL`, when actually `toPtr` is pointing to an empty list. So why does this happen?

This is the full code: https://hastebin.com/adikunevus.cpp

I'm sorry but the `printf` part is in Italian, but basically, if you select the 2 choice and then you choose which column of game stacks takes the card, and then you choose the column of base stacks to bring the card (so basically the program executes the `move_card` function), it does not work because it goes inside the `if (toPtr != NULL)` when it shouldn't.

So I don't get what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Pointers don't know the size of the array, they're just pointers. To know if it's "empty" you need other information.

Comment: It'd help if you included more information on the structures involved here. There's all kinds of definitions that are absent.

Comment: Think about it. How could `Stack *toPtr = &(topstacks[pos2]);` ever be `NULL`? You're asking about the address of something and you're going to get one. You'll never get `&x[y]` suddenly being `NULL`, it's not like Ruby or JavaScript where referencing an array element out of bounds returns `nil` or `undefined`.

Comment: @tadman so what's the best approach to check if the list is empty?

Comment: Define "empty"? You need a counter to keep track of how many entries, of the total it *could* have, are populated.

Comment: @tadman so I need to pass this counter everytime in every function? for empty I mean that there is not item inside.

Comment: Pointers are just memory addresses, they have *no* idea about how many entries they point to. That's why you see a lot of C code that takes arguments in pairs like `char* data, size_t size` because you need to know.

Comment: @tadman, I know that. I don't even know why you say me I need a size. I don't have to use it. I can just look up the first element, and if there isn't, the stack is empty. The thing is that I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what your code is actually doing, but it's very convoluted and hard to follow. What is the objective of `move_card`? You call these things "stacks" but you mean just a stack of...decks of cards? What I find confusing is there's both linked lists going on as well as arrays. Usually it's one *or* the other. That and `move_card` appears to move...decks? You also allocate a bunch of `Stack` objects which apparently have `Card` arrays in them yet those are never initialized, they're just junk data.

Comment: As a suggestion, this code would be way easier to follow if it had better naming conventions, and stuck to one model of storing data at a time. For example, allocating each `Stack` entry individually as you chain them together makes things much tidier, you can `push` and `pop` entries with ease.

Comment: I think what you're trying to do with `move_card` is pull a linked-list element from one "stack" and insert it into the other, using those positions specified as to where to pull from and insert to. Is that correct? Also just to confirm, this is for C, not CPP as your link implies?

Comment: @tadman you are right, really thanks for the help, you are putting too much effort to help me ahaha. I fixed it here btw: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64075185/13394732 and again, thanks you for the help/suggestions!