# What's the best approach to check if in a array of lists a single list is empty after I used calloc?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list, stack

Usually, when I use linked lists, I write:

```
struct node *startPtr = NULL;
```

so I check later if is it NULL, and if it is, it means that the list is empty.

But in this code:

```
struct card{
    char face[3];
    char suit[4];
};
typedef struct card Card;

struct stack{
    Card cardd;
    struct stack *nextPtr;
};
typedef struct stack Stack;

int main(){
    /*
    creation of *stacks also with calloc
    */
    Stack *topstacks = calloc(4,sizeof(Stack));    // array of lists initialized by calloc
    /*
    scanf pos1, pos2 to switch
    */
    move_card(stacks, topstacks, pos1, pos2);
}

int move_card(Stack *stacks, Stack *topstacks, unsigned int pos1, unsigned int pos2){
    Stack *prevfromPtr;
    Stack *fromPtr = &(stacks[pos1]);
    Stack *toPtr = &(topstacks[pos2]); 
    while(fromPtr->nextPtr!=NULL){
        prevfromPtr = fromPtr;
        fromPtr = fromPtr->nextPtr;
    }
    Stack *newmovingcard = calloc(1,sizeof(Stack));
    newmovingcard->cardd = fromPtr->cardd;
    newmovingcard->nextPtr = NULL; 
    if (toPtr!=NULL){                       // here I'd like to check if the list is empty and has not any item. This way it does not work because toPtr can't be NULL, it's a pointer
        while(toPtr->nextPtr!=NULL){
            toPtr = toPtr->nextPtr;
        } 
        toPtr->nextPtr = newmovingcard; 
        free(fromPtr);
        prevfromPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        return 0;
    } else {
        toPtr->cardd = newmovingcard->cardd;
        toPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        free(fromPtr);
        prevfromPtr->nextPtr = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have an array of lists (topstacks), initialized with calloc. And in the commented line inside `move_card`, I need to check if the single list of the array of lists is empty. But I don't know how to do that.

Here is the full code, but some parts with printf are in italian, so sorry for that: https://wtools.io/paste-code/b2gz

Comment: There's two ways to do linked lists. One is to have a function which takes a pointer to a pointer and will allocate if the "root" is NULL, another is where you have a stub "head" node that always exists but is otherwise ignored.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working with two linked lists simultaneously is kind of fussy and annoying, but it is doable:

```c
int move_card(Stack **source, Stack **target, int source_pos, int target_pos) {
    // Walk through the linked list, but in every case stop one short of the
    // insertion point

    // Walk through the source chain and identify which pointer needs
    // to be manipulated.
    for (int i = 0; i < source_pos; ++i) {
        if (*source == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }

        source = &((*source)->nextPtr);
    }

    // Walk through the target chain and identify the insertion point.
    for (int i = 0; i < target_pos - 1; ++i) {
        if (*target == NULL) {
            return 1;
        }

        target = &((*target)->nextPtr);
    }

    // Capture the pointer we're actually moving
    Stack* moving = *source;

    // Skip this link in the chain by reassigning source
    *source = moving->nextPtr;

    // Capture the record that's being bumped
    Stack* bumped = *target;

    // Reassign the target
    *target = moving;

    // Re-link the bumped entry back in the chain
    moving->nextPtr = bumped;

    return 0;
}
```

Where I've taken the liberty of renaming a few things to make this easier to understand. Notice how it uses a double pointer so it can manipulate the original pointers if necessary. When removing the first card from a linked list, the pointer to the "head" entry must change.

Here's a more complete "demo" harness for that code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct stack {
    char card[2];
    struct stack *nextPtr;
};
typedef struct stack Stack;

Stack* make_stack(char face, char suit, Stack* nextPtr) {
    Stack* stack = calloc(1, sizeof(Stack));
    stack->card[0] = face;
    stack->card[1] = suit;
    stack->nextPtr = nextPtr;

    return stack;
}

void print_stack(Stack* stack) {
    while (stack) {
        printf("%c%c ", stack->card[0], stack->card[1]);
        stack = stack->nextPtr;
    }

    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Stack* source = make_stack('A', 'S', make_stack('2', 'S', make_stack('3', 'S', NULL)));
    Stack* target = NULL;

    print_stack(source);

    move_card(&source, &target, 2, 0);

    print_stack(source);
    print_stack(target);

    return 0;
}
```

Where that uses a simplified Card model.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to assign `nextPtr` to the same element or you can introduce a special global item which will mean an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `malloc` with `memset` instead of `calloc` you can set your value as your own "void" value.

I mean this kind of thing :

```
int* example;

example=malloc(100*sizeof(int));    // allocate memory to store 100 int

if(example){
    memset(example,1,100*sizeof(int));  // initialize it with value 1
}
```